# Составить название переменной для списка

Tags: python

В коде нужно перебрать разные списки с близким названием (g_1,g_2,g_3). Пробую решить вопрос через `'g_'+str(f)` - тоесть как я полагал, таким образом смогу сформировать название списка и дальше уже перебирать из него поочередно элементы (`a = 'g_'+str(f) и a[i]` вместо `g_1[i],g_2[i],g_3[i]`) При исполнение кода получаю ошибку `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` - что она значит понятно, но как тогда нужно правильно написать?

```
g_1 = list(.......................................)
g_2 = list(.......................................)
g_3 = list(.......................................)

f_l = [1,2,3]

for f in f_l:

    a = 'g_'+str(f)
    
    for i in range(len):

        if a[i]>s:
            ...
```

Comment: Может стоит использовать globals с сортировкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать eval

```
a = eval('g_'+str(f))
```

Answer (score 3):

Гораздо проще, понятнее и правильнее воспользоваться **словарем** в данном случае. Словари придуманы для того, чтобы быстро и удобно обращаться к данным по ключу:

```
lists = [...]
data = {i:l for i,l in enumerate(lists)}
```

В результате вы получите словарь с порядковым номером списка в качестве ключа и соответствующем ему списку в качестве значения.

PS ключ можно сформировать так, как нужно именно вам.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно стоит переосмыслить подход:

```
g_1 = list(.......................................)
g_2 = list(.......................................)
g_3 = list(.......................................)

f_l = [g_1, g_2, g_3]

for f in f_l:
    a = f
    for i in range(len):
        if a[i]>s:
            ...
```

`eval` — плохая практика

Answer (score 0):

Либо использовать `itertools` . Примерно так:

```
from itertools import chain
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [7,8,9]
for i in chain(l1,l2,l3):
    print(i, end=' ')  # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```